# MySQL: How to combine a column referenced multiple times from another table and assign proper aliases?

Tags: mysql

The question I've got here may look silly, but it drives me a bit crazy, as I can't get how the MySQL join works.

I have 2 tables:

```
user;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

game;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| source_id*         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| target_id*         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

`game.source_id` and `game.target_id` are constraints that reference the `user.id`.

Now I want to select everything from `game` table and I want to include in the result names of 2 users, since `game` has 2 users. And I want those columns to be named as `target_name` and `source_name` specifically.

**Tried this query**:

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    u.name
FROM
    game g
RIGHT JOIN
    user u
ON
    u.id = g.source_id 
OR
    u.id = g.target_id
WHERE
    g.source_id = 1
OR
    g.target_id = 1
;
```

But as you may have noticed, I don't alias `u.name` as `target_name` or `source_name` because I don't know how to do that and end result looks like this:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | bo   |
| 1  | al   |
| 2  | jo   |
| 2  | jay  |
+----+------+
```

As you can see, there's a `game` appearing multiple times in the result.

**Expected result:**

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | target_name | source_name |
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 1  | bo          | al          |
| 2  | jo          | jay         |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join the table `user` twice on table `game` in order to get the two names for the game. I have added `COALESCE` because it is useful for for showing descriptive value for `NULL` columns.If for instance there is no value for source or target, the value that will be shown is `-no value-.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.name,'-no source-') sourceName,
        COALESCE(c.name,'-no target-') targetName
FROM    game a
        LEFT JOIN `user` b
            on b.id = a.source_ID
        LEFT JOIN `user` c
            on on c.id = a.target_id
-- your condition here
```

Comment: Thanks. That works too. Does this mean that it will run through the `user` table 2 times for each join?

Comment: yes,but it will be fast since those keys that defines that relationship were already index.

Comment: Thanks for extra info on COALESCE. But, do I understand correctly, that if I add a `WHERE` clause, then I won't need it (the `COALESCE`) since game cannot exists without `source_id` or `target_id`?

Comment: if that's so, use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and you can now remove `COALESCE`

Comment: Can you please give short tip on why `INNER JOIN` is preferred over `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` in this particular case?

Comment: In some context I read, it stated that, `A LEFT JOIN is absolutely not faster than an INNER JOIN. In fact, it's slower; by definition, an outer join (LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN) has to do all the work of an INNER JOIN plus the extra work of null-extending the results. It would also be expected to return more rows, further increasing the total execution time simply due to the larger size of the result set.`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    source.name,
    target.name
FROM
    game g
LEFT JOIN
    user source
ON
    source.id = g.source_id 
LEFT JOIN
    user target
ON
    target.id = g.target_id
WHERE
    g.source_id = 1
OR
    g.target_id = 1
;
```

the where clause is optional and is intended to search all games played by user id=1, as source or as target.

Comment: Thanks. It does the job and I can alias `source.name` and `target.name`. And thanks for pointing out for the WHERE clause. In the final app i need it, because this is exactly what I need to do - get all games for particular user.